# OpenLiberty MP Config Sample getProperties() repetitive called

Tags: open-liberty, microprofile

I tried the OpenLiberty MP Config Sample (guide-microprofile-config), so far it works. But when analyzing it more closely, I found out that the method 
getProperties() in the file CustomConfigSource is called several times in repetition. This is a behavior I did not expect.
In the file InventoryConfig there are variables injected statically and dynamically (by using "Provider<>"). But this code should only be called when I call a REST Service. So my question what does trigger getProperties() all the times? How can I prevent it.
Actually with my implementation I want to access a database and do a query and I wanted to put the logic into getProperties() which now it seems a bad idea.

best regards
Igor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OpenLiberty, user provided ConfigSources are dynamic and so the system re-reads them regularly. The default refresh interval can be adjusted by setting a System Property called `microprofile.config.refresh.rate`. The value is in milliseconds. If you set it to zero then it won't refesh at all. For further information, see here (look for the section titled "Dynamic property values"):

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/cwlp_microprofile_overview.html

If you would like to comment on or contribute to future MicroProfile Config versions, please get involved at
https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-config/

Comment: Thank you for your help, now my solution rocks!

Answer (score 1):

By the way, the above described behavior is Open Liberty implementation detail. The current MicroProfile Config specification does not mandate a way to deal with Dynamic config sources. The upcoming MicroProfile Config release will address this area.

Comment: Hi Emily, thank you for your valuable answer, I'm looking forward to get the newest MicroProfile Config Release and I will surely use it with Open Liberty. The dynamic config feature will help me a lot with the use cases we actually have at the moment.